# Use /etc/hosts/ for jenkins to resolve host

Tags: jenkins, hosts

I am trying to apply Jenkins job to a host. However the host name is not resolvable. I made an entry in the /etc/hosts file:

192.168.10.10 myhosts

From Jenkins server I can ping the hostname and the correct IP is resolved. However when I run my Jenkins Job, I get the following error:

```
skipping: no hosts matched
```

How can I get Jenkins to use the /etc/hosts file?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to find out how to do it? Could you share a solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are running the build using docker? I had the same problem and I solved it with the option [--add-host](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file---add-host)